# Changing recurrence to matrix

Tags: probability, matrices, recurrence-relations

$$F(x) = aF(x-k+1) + bF(x-k+2) + cF(x-k+4) + dF(x-k+7)$$

where $F(x) = 1$ if $x<k$.

$a,b,c,d,k$ are known (and positive) and $x$ is chosen.

Can anyone show how to set this up in matrix form using $k=4$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $k=4$ the relationship is anticipatory because of $d F(x-4+7)$ term and if $d \neq 0$ then you may have to solve for $F(x+3)$. Also, $F(x-k+4)$ would cause problems if $c=1$.

I will show how to do it for $k>7$ say $k=8$.

Then

$$F(x) = a F(x-7) + b F(x-6)+cF(x-4)+d F(x-1)$$

So we have to go all the way back to $F(x-7)$. So let 
$$G(x) = \pmatrix{F(x)\\F(x-1)\\F(x-2)\\F(x-3)\\F(x-4)\\F(x-5) \\ F(x-6)}
$$
Then 
$$G(x-1) = \pmatrix{F(x-1)\\F(x-2)\\F(x-3)\\F(x-4)\\F(x-5) \\ F(x-6)\\F(x-7)}
$$
Hence
$$
G(x) = \pmatrix{ d & 0&0&c&0&b&a\\
1 & 0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&1 & 0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1 & 0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1 & 0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1 & 0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0 & 1&0\\
} G(x-1)$$

**Added in response to OP's comment**

Suppose $k=5$. Then the original equation is

$$
F(x) = a F(x-4)+bF(x-3)+cF(x-1)+dF(x+2)$$
replace $x$ by $x-2$ to get
$$
F(x-2)=a F(x-6)+bF(x-5)+c F(x-3)+d F(x)$$
Solving we get
$$
F(x) = \frac{1}{d} F(x-2)-\frac a d F(x-6) -\frac b d F(x-5) -\frac c d F(x-3)
$$

Now proceed as before.

**Additional comments**
Note that $F(x)$ depends on past values of $F$. $G$ is just a vector with $F$ and its past values. How long should $G$ be? At least as long as to be able to write $F(x)$ in terms of $G(x-1)$. Make it longer does not *hurt* except we need to keep *more* of the past history.

Comment: Try out an example. Write out $F(0)$, $F(1)$ etc. up to some point say $F(10)$. The actual values are not important. Just pick some random values so you can understand how it works. Pick $k=8$ first so you don't get bogged down by algebra. Now write $G(10)$. Also calculate $F(11)$ but use the variables $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$. Next write $G(11)$ and see how $G(11)$ can be obtained from the matrix. It should become obvious once you do it. There is no way I can explain it without you actually **trying it out***.

Comment: You don't seem to understand. The matrix formulation does not depend on specific values. Again, first understand how it works for $k=8$. Use actual values if you want. The important thing is to see how $G(x)$ and $G(x-1)$ relate. The first element of $G(x)$ is $F(x)$. Again you have to do it. It is like teaching you how to swim or ride a bicycle. All the explanation won't help till you actually try it! So the question to you is. Do you have values of $F(x)$ to say $x=20$. Have you written down $G(19)$ and $G(20)$? You have to do this

Comment: Once you have the matrix, $G(n) = A^n G(0)$ where $A$ is the matrix I show. Not sure where you are not understanding

Comment: That depends on the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$. If one or more have magnitude greater than $1$ then the numbers will grow exponentially. If all are less than one, then the terms will go to zero. If some have magnitude 1 but not repeated, then the terms will remain bounded. If there are repeated eigenvalues of magnitude 1, then you need to do more careful analysis.

Comment: $G(0)$ will depend on $F(-1)$, $F(-2)$ etc. If these are not specified, then $G(x)$ may have to start at some $x>0$. If $G(x)$ goes back to $F(x-n)$ and $F(x)$ is given for $x\ge0$ then $G(n)$ is the first $G$ that is specified. You then need $G(m) = A^{m-n}G(n)$ for $m\ge n$.

Comment: yes, I am assuming that $G(7)$ can be defined.